# Is there any Python API to fetch the list of all the active resources(VM's, Buckets, Datasets, etc) and their metadata for a project in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

I'm looking for a Python API to fetch instances, buckets, datasets, data proc, and other resource metadata for my project in GCP. I looked into *cloud monitoring API*, but it only gives resource descriptors, metric descriptors, and time series data. I've explored *resource manager API*, but I am unable to fetch resources at the service level for a project.

For example, I required VM metadata like instance_id, OS installed, memory config, machine series, etc. Similarly, I required metadata for storage, bigquery, dataproc, and other services too.

Is there any such API available in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can use the Cloud Asset Inventory API to fetch the list of active resources for our project. Check the permissions required to list resources from here: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/access-control

Here is a code sample in Python that uses google-cloud-asset API to fetch all resources with metadata:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import asset_v1


credentials_path = ''
credentials = 
service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials_path)
project_id = ''
client = asset_v1.AssetServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
results = client.search_all_resources(scope=project_id)
for res in results:
    print(res)
```

You can explore more about the API here: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudasset/latest